# Shortening a long technical process of evaluating a function and using that value as one of the terms in the function itself.

Tags: functions

Imagine an f(x) = x + xh - h

Let's say I evaluate this at a certain value of x and want to use the value of the function at that x as my new x and to keep using the new function value as the x value multiple times.

For example:

h is a constant equal to 0.1

starting x value is 3.2

The function would be 3.42. Then use 3.42 as the new x value and use that value of the function(3.662) as my new x and keep repeating this a number of times.

How can I implement that in the original function and adjust the x value in any way according to the number of times I want to repeat the operation of using the function value itself as the new x value? I don't care if the adjustment is logarithmic or exponential or complicated in any way.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are doing $f(x)$, $f(f(x))$, $f(f(f(x)))$, and so on. Doing this $n$ times can be denoted as $f^n(x)$.

Comment: How can I put that in a calculator?

Comment: You can't. I am just showing the mathematical notation for what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this easier, I will factor out an $h$ from the first two terms and say:
$$f(x)=x(h+1)-h$$
This way, $x$ only shows up once, so if we repeat an application, we only need to substitute for $x$ once.

Now, let's try to find a pattern.
$$f(f(x))=f(x)(h+1)-h=(x(h+1)-h)(h+1)-h=x(h+1)^2-h(h+1)-h$$
$$f(f(f(x)))=f(f(x))(h+1)-h=(x(h+1)^2-h(h+1)-h)(h+1)-h \\=x(h+1)^3-h(h+1)^2-h(h+1)-h$$
Hopefully, you see the pattern here. For $n$ applications of $f$, we have $x(h+1)^n$ and then we subtract by $h(h+1)^k$ for $1 \leq k < n$. Thus, we get:
$$f^n(x)=x(h+1)^n-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}h(h+1)^k$$
The latter is the partial sum of a geometric series, so by using the partial sum formula, we get:
$$f^n(x)=x(h+1)^n-h\frac{1-(h+1)^n}{1-(h+1)}=x(h+1)^n-h\frac{1-(h+1)^n}{-h}=x(h+1)^n+1-(h+1)^n$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I am a high school student and want to take the AP Calculus BC exam, and I saw Euler's method and how long it could be so I wanted to come up with an equation to solve instantly instead of doing a robot's job. I did exactly what you did but without factoring the x term, so the pattern was more difficult to see. I even tried to find a constant in terms of the initial terms which you raise the initial function to to achieve my aim. Your explanation was clear and easy to follow!

Comment: @InterestedLearner Glad I could help! Just so you know, although I do know basic differential/integral calculus already, I am also a high school student and I will take AP Calc BC next year, so it is interesting to see what new stuff I will learn.

Comment: Sadly, there isn't much new stuff I learned over the basic differential and integral calculus. It is only logarithmic/exponential functions and integration by parts of trig functions and the infinite series. You can learn all three of these things in roughly 2 or 3 hours. I do have some undergrad and grad math books as pdfs, I can send them to you if you'd like. They are crazy advanced, but more interesting than anything high school related.

Comment: I would definitely appreciate you sending me some pdfs of textbooks! Personally, I usually look for online textbooks from [this list of Open Content Maths Curriculum Textbooks](http://linear.ups.edu/curriculum.html).

Comment: How would you like me to send them?

Comment: Can you put the links to the PDFs/titles of the textbooks [in a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and then give the link to the pastebin to me by commenting on this answer again? You can also e-mail the PDFs to me at fakety.fakefake651@gmail.com (yes, that is my e-mail address; it is just not my primary one because I do not want my primary e-mail address to be known publicly). Also, again, I really do appreciate you doing this.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Kzj4ZGLi

Comment: @InterestedLearner Thank you so much for these books! I will really learn a lot from these and I truly appreciate it!